# Is there a way to increase numeric value in a string variable? [Python]

Tags: python, string

I'm trying some web-scraping which requires to loop through some elements having attribute in a string format. But the string is a numeric value which increases throughout the element.

```
data-id="1"
```

Is there a way to increase the value of data-id to "2" to "3" so on while it remains in string format?

Comment: `str(int(data_id)+1)`?

Comment: `mystr = str(int(mystr) + 1)` would do it.

Comment: Are u using Selenium ?

Comment: It supposed to be `data_id`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, convert the string to an integer, you can do that with the `int` builtin:

`int(data_id)`

Then add 1 to that integer:

`int(data_id) + 1`

Finally, convert the new integer back to a string, you can do that with the `str` builtin:

`str(int(data_id) + 1)`

E.g.

```
>>> data_id = "1"
>>> data_id = str(int(data_id) + 1)
>>> data_id
'2'
```

Answer (score 1):

I will just explain the response In the comment of @rdas and @Jax Teller code:

- 1. First, you convert your string to integer value, for this we use `int(my_string)`, let assume, you store the result in a variable called int_val like `int_val = int(my_string)`,
- 2. Then you increase you integer value `int_val = int_val + 1`,
- 3. At the end you convert back the result to string using str(...) : `my_str=str(int_val)`.

```
my_string = "1"
int_val = int(my_string)
int_val = int_val + 1
my_string = str(int_val)
```

**These steps are compacted in one single line like `my_str = str(int(my_str)+1)`.**
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

something like the below

```
def increment_str(string):
    return str(int(string) + 1)


print(increment_str("12"))
```

output

```
13
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use an integer variable in the first place and convert it to a string as needed:

```py
data_id = 1

fetch_element_(data_id=str(data_id))

data_id += 1

fetch_element_(data_id=str(data_id))
```

Now, you can simplify that code using a for-loop and the built-in `range` function:

```py
for data_id in range(1,4):  # This will loop through the numbers [1, 2, 3]
    fetch_element_(data_id=str(data_id))
```

When your first id is given as a string in the beginning, you can use the `int` constructor to convert it to an int, as suggested in the other answers:

```py
data_id = int("1")  # or int(some_string_variable)
```